# "to use in case of emergency"

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation, postmodification

a. This is a gun, to use in case of emergency.

b. This is a gun, to use only in case of emergency.

c. This is a gun, to be used in case of emergency.

d. This is a gun, to be used only in case of emergency.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

Obviously, 'only' changes the meaning somewhat. But does the comma work in those sentences? It is there to give the sentence a double focus. We are conveying two bits of information that are equally important. It is possible that the second part is added as an afterthought. In that case, it becomes less important.

Comment: I don't think (a) and (b) work. (c) and (d) can work if you did either of these two changes: *"This is a gun, and it is to be used in case of an emergency."* or *"This is a gun; it is to be used in case of an emergency."*

Comment: @AIQ Granted without context (a) and (b) as they stand are not good English, but they don't sound _wrong_. Consider: "Here is a book to read." (Here is a book _for you_ to read). "Here is a gun to use." (Here is a gun _for you_ to use.) And also equally common and idiomatic: "The food is ready to eat."

Comment: @EddieKal All your examples are correct, and I don't object to that construction at all (i.e., Here is a gun to use). I objected to the way they are punctuated. If the comma is to be used in those sentences, then there should be an 'and'. And then the subject needs to be repeated. In my rephrased versions (c and d), I added the subject (= it) in the second clause after the punctuation - essentially making them independent clauses. I felt I couldn't do that with a and b because of "use" instead of "used": *This is a gun, and it is to be **use** in case of emergency.* That doesn't work.

Comment: @AIQ I hear you. Syntactically I agree with you: your versions are much better. But the funny thing is I actually think (a) and (b), ungrammatical and jarring though they may be, work better in fiction. I could totally see them spoken by a character, planted by the author to reflect the ungrammaticality and pauses of in the flow of speech.

Comment: @EddieKal Oh yes, I agree with you. It would be fine in speech. For some weird reason, I just read them in my head now with a Liam Neeson voice.

Answer (score 0):

Punctuation is best not thought about as being part of grammar at all because it does not pertain to the spoken language.

Punctuation involves a set of conventions that help elucidate written communication, which does not have the clues given by stress and tone of voice in the spoken language. Those conventions are set down in style manuals. Different style manuals stipulate somewhat different conventions. So it is risky to make absolute assertions about what is "proper" punctuation.

With all that said, the comma appears weird in all four examples. A good informal guide on whether a comma is needed or not is whether or not there would be a slight pause in speech. In your examples, a pause in speech would not be normal where you insert a comma. Of course, the examples do not reflect normal speech in any event. What would be more frequent would be

> Use this gun in case of emergency
>
> Use this gun only in case of emergency
>
> This gun is to be used in case of emergency
>
> This gun is to be used only in case of emergency

None of them require the insertion of a comma according to any style manual that I remember.